# How to programmatically access JDT icons with an eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I'd like to use built-in JDT icons inside my plugin: http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-icons.htm

How can I access them from within my code? The following code seems to list some shared images, but only standard UI icons of eclise, not JDT specific (I need icons for private/public/... methods/fields in Java):

```
IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
ISharedImages images = workbench.getSharedImages();
Image image = images.getImage(ISharedImages.IMG_OBJ_FOLDER);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just found it out: On my above code, instead of using `org.eclipse.ui.ISharedImages` (as returned by `workbench.getSharedImages()`, just use `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.ISharedImages`, which returns constants for jdt images.

**Update:**

The above gave me a NullPointerException. The following is working now:

```
ISharedImages images = JavaUI.getSharedImages();
Image image = images.getImage(ISharedImages.IMG_WHATEVER);
```

Comment: You are aware of the fact that you now require a JDT to be installed at every user of your plugin? If your plugin does not add some Java related features to the JDT (but targets a completely different audience), then this is really horrible.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this. But my tool is used to visualize Java objects, so they obviously are using JDT, or they should install it immediately. :D
Btw, this was the reason why a had the idea to use JDT's icons, I had made my own before, but it was not too intuitive to some people.  But if they're using eclipse for Java, they probably know these icons.